# Vue.Js axios get request not going through

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to send a get request using axios from vuex store.js file,  the api that i am using is this 
https://openlibrary.org/dev/docs/api/search
when i search the api right inside the browser it works just fine, however, it doesn't do anything when sending the request using axios from the app that i am working on..

here is the **store.js** code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {
        findBook({commit,  dispatch}, book) {
            console.log('logged before the request'); //this gets logged to the console

            axios.get('http://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=the+lord+of+the+rings')
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(`logged after the request`); //this doesn't get logged 
                    console.log(res);
                }).catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }
})
```

furthermore, i get no errors at all from the catch block,

could someone tell me what am i missing here? 
thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing being output from the catch method?

Comment: nothing at all, have no idea why !!

Comment: where/when did you dispatch this action ?

Comment: I dispatched this action from a vue component upon firing a click event, but I am sure the issue has nothing to do with that, simply because i get the message above logged before sending the request, but i get neither the msg inside the request nor the response itself

Comment: okay, what does your network panel say ? did the request get performed or not at all ?

Comment: I recreated it and it works exactly like intended. Maybe try to delete the axios node module und install again.

Comment: @sarlem the only xhr request is with a status 200 but i get nothing from the response block

Comment: @BennettDams, I did uninstall the axios pckg and reinstalled it again, and still, the same result, I am really confused now, did u use it with vuex ? and the URL, is it the same like in the post ?

Comment: Yes, Vuex and exactly your code. The error has to be somewhere else.

Comment: @BennettDams but if the error was from the vue component where i dispatch the action, i wouldn't have gotten the first msg logged to the console right?!

Comment: Yes, so it has something to do with your console, browser, cache, etc.

Comment: If you get nothing on response to your request this means axios Promises can't finish so it wont trigger your then/catch.
Can you add to your question the exact request with payload and everything ?

Comment: I didn't send a payload from the vue component i don't need it as i was actually just testing the API itself, if you check the URL with the GET request, it include the search query, and if you copy the same exact URL to the browser, you will get the required responss.. @BennettDams said he recreated the the app with my exact same code and he got the expected response, so i don't really know what the heck is going on in my side :S

Comment: Try `https` instead of `http`:   `axios.get('https://openlibrary.org/search.json?title=the+lord+of+the+rings')`

Comment: Here is a working example with your code (besides `https`):  https://codesandbox.io/s/0x5vp6jk4v

Comment: I forked the code in the link, and yes it is actually working perfectly fine there, however, i still have a problem in my local machine, this time i tried the same app in firefox instead of chrome, tho i got an entirely new error in the console, It says Network error and said `CORS request did not succeed` which i honestly didn't quit get.. in addition to that, i didn't even get the msg to be logged before sending the request as in chrome. this is the forked code in codesandbox
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yvpr20j34) 
but anyways tho, I really can't thank you enough :)